# burying 3 core cable in metal conduit

Tags: electrical, uk, underground

what is the BS7671 code for running 3core flexible cable in metal conduit that is buried underground. because the environment that i am in is sand. i know in the US they run PVC conduit when running a wire in the ground.

Comment: Rigid and IMC galvanized steel conduits are also used underground in the US. Cable is not usually run in conduit, and I doubt that differs much UK/US since the physical realities of pulling cables .vs. pulling wires in conduit are not country specific, but hopefully we'll get some UK responders who know.

Comment: Also, in the US, conduit doesn't really "buy you anything" in terms of weather resistance, i.e. conduits are presumed to be 100% full of water all the time so the wire must be wet-rated.

Comment: @ecnerwal in the US emt was also approved for direct burial in the 2017 code 358.10.A.1 but I agree conduit is not normally used for cable, individual wires yes, cables are more expensive and hard to pull compared to individual wires.